# How do I get my gravatar to show on my profile?

Tags: support, gravatar

I signed up for a gravatar some time ago, but it doesn't show on my profile.  Sorry  for the dumb question, but now what do I do?

Comment: Im curious why people would downvote this?

Answer (score 1):

This is your Gravatar as I see it:

[image]

Not yours? Then you have a different email address with Gravatar and Stack Overflow. Change the email address in your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/302430) to the same one you use on Gravatar.

Answer (score 0):

Your current Image does not look like the default SO images, are you sure that is not your gravatar?

To get it to work though is rather easy. Just create a gravatar for the same email address you are registered here with and it will automatically pick it up for you.

Comment: It's automatically not picking anything up.  My gravatar looks nothing like the image here.

Answer (score 0):

if it's not working perhaps your profile is cached in your browser, try opening up an incognito window in Chrome  (or similar in another browser) or emptying your cache?